# How to stop webform from sending an email

Tags: 7, webforms

**I'm using Drupal 7.12 / Webform 3**

How do I stop email from being sent upon a webform submission? I want to do this conditionally so I need to use a hook. I still want everything else to go through correctly (i.e. confirmation page, db entry for submission).

I see that there are these lines in `function webform_client_form_submit($form, &$form_state)`

```
if (!$is_draft && !$form_state['values']['details']['finished']) {
    $submission = webform_get_submission($node->webform['nid'], $sid, TRUE);
    webform_submission_send_mail($node, $submission);
  }
```

How do I hook into that and stop it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go the end of the function [webform_submission_send_mail](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_submission_send_mail/7)() inside the file [webform.submissions.inc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/7) (inside weform module's *include* directory), you'll notice that the webform module using the function [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) to send the mail.

So a better place to change the behavior of the mail from being sent (*alter* in Drupal terms) is [hook_mail_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7)(), which is used to alter an email message created by using `drupal_mail()` function.

Implementation of the *hook* to stop the e-mails:

```
function MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  //You can do your conditional check here and depending on that
  //you can set the value of $message['send'] to false to stop the mail from being sent. 
  //place the line below inside conditional loop, or else it'll stop every mail from being sent ;-)
  $message['send'] = FALSE; 
}
```

**Note:** This *hook* will only work if the mail is generated by `drupal_mail()`. If you're sending mail by some other menthod, it'll not be invoked. But, by default Webform module uses `drupal_mail()` as mentioned earlier, so there's nothing to worry :-)
You'll also need to clear the caches to make the change effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use webform with Rules and [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules). Are your conditions something complicated that Rules cannot implement?

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove all recipients on here:

```
yoursite.com/node/XXX/webform/emails
```

when there are no recipients no emails will be sent.

Comment: Yeah. I only want to stop the emails under certain conditions which I will calculate in my custom module. So I still need email addresses in there.

Comment: Ok, then you should write your own submit function, in fact you can copy and paste the code of webform_client_form_submit and just modify it to your needs. And then in your iimplementation of hook_form_alter for the webform you should replace default submit function with yours.

Comment: @Alex Petrov I upvoted your comment, parhaps you should update your answer with this solution

Answer (score 0):

you even do not need override webform_client_form_submit function, because 'webform_client_form_submit' function works with $form['#node']->webform['emails'] array, which you can modify in form_alter hook. (unset your email for some specific condition). I've tested it on webform 4v, maybe for 3v object can have other structure, but i think it also have to work

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in hook_webform_submission_insert.  I just looped through the emails and changed their status. In my case I wanted to enable them so set them to 1.

```
   foreach ($node->webform['emails'] as $key => $email) {
    $node->webform['emails'][$key]['status'] = 1 // or 0 to disable;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same approach as Cameron, by using the insert hook. 
Setting the status for each email did not work for me however.

I managed to get it to work by unsetting the emails I did not want to go out.

```
foreach ($node->webform['emails'] as $key => $email) {
  unset($node->webform['emails'][$key]);
}
```