# How can I programmatically stop webform from sending an email?

Tags: webforms, emails, 10

I need to stop sending my webform submission email programmatically and conditionally. By conditionally I mean I have two contact forms and two locales on my Drupal application. I have a custom configuration in the admin end based upon which I will be allowing/disallowing the webform submission emails only for the contact form and locale I choose at the backend configuration.

I have seen an answer at [How to stop webform from sending an email](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26058/how-to-stop-webform-from-sending-an-email) that point me to do this in hook_webform_submission_insert but my preference is do do it via a handler. I'm not able to comment on that answer as i don't have enough stackoverflow reputation.

I know in Drupal 7 we were able to do it by simply setting the flag $message['send'] = false; Is there a way to in a similar way in Drupal 10? This might be simple  but I could not find a way around this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter() to Conditionally enable or disable a handler:

```
function Mymodulename_webform_handler_invoke_alter(\Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface $handler, $method_name, array &$args) {
  $webform = $handler->getWebform();
  $webform_id = $handler->getWebform()->id();
  $handler_id = $handler->getHandlerId();
  if($webform_id == 'webform_machine_name' && $handler_id == 'handler_machine_name'){
     // Add logic here to disable webform handler programatically
      $operation = 'disable';
      // call disable() function
      $handler->$operation();
      // Save the webform.
      $webform->save();
  } 
}
```

Note: Make sure clear cache & check email handler list of webform whose email handler you want to disable , you 'll see email handler 'll disble for eg: /admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/handlers

For more documentation you can check [here](https://api.druphelp.com/api/webform/webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter/8.5)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is something I did not know. But what I actually wanted to know is - How to prevent webform from sending an email programmatically based on a conditional logic.

Comment: Did you try this above mentioned hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter by adding your custom logic?

Comment: I do not want to disable a handler, but rather I want to disable the email sent by two variants of contact us webforms based on a logic in code.